# binding process with angularjs and kendo ui

Tags: javascript, angularjs, wpf, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I'm changing a wpf project to web application. The technologies are angular and kendo ui. I'm new to the web front end and there're something confuse.

1. Is there a wpf DataTrigger mechanism in angular? For example, my data grid contains 2 columns A and B, column B's value is based on column A's value, and it could be changed dynamically if A's value changed. In WPF, we can use DataTrigger to deal with it easily, any similar mechanism in angular?
2. loading data from service and bind them to data grid, where can I define the viewmodel? The process is, getting data from service, then process the data, create a collection to bind to grid. the model type in the collection is different with the raw data, where can I define the model? And where can I process the raw data?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to define additional fields in model

```
model: {
        fullname: function() {
          return this.firstname + ' ' + this.lastname;
        }
      }
```

so fullname is calculated field and firstname and lastname are field names that are automatically included in the model (they are in the jsondata)

you can then use this in a template with something like `${fullname()}`

If you really need triggers like behavior, than you should impliment your solution on `observable objects`. You can read about them here:

http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/observableobject

---

Second question is really about basics features, first read that article

http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid

And my reccomendation is avoide complex computations on client side, that way you should return bind-ready data from server and load it to data source without any additional processing. But if you can't avoid that, you should impliment custom read function of `kendo.dataSource`:

```
var dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
transport: {
    read: function (e) {
        //here you can process sampleData, then load it to DS
        e.success(sampleData);
        // on failure
        //e.error("XHR response", "status code", "error message");
    }
}
```

}

Also read about CRUD operations here:

http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/framework/datasource/crud